# Legal to live homeless (in workplace) and have a driver license in California?

Tags: california

I'm not sure if this question is related to here or not, but:

So, I got a job in California and I'm moving there in 2 weeks. But, I have decided to live in my workplace for the next 2 years and I'm not going to rent an apartment. Is it legal and possible to give my workplace address as the address for my Driver's License?

Since one my posts is getting deleted because it wasn't an answer, I'm re-adding it here:

"Thank you all for the answers. So, when I say living in work place it doesn't mean I'm going to walk around in pajamas all the day around the work and be totally obvious. It means I'll be the same as anyone else, only when everyone else is leaving work at 5pm for example, I'll still be staying there, and at night around 11pm I'll just pull out a super tiny collectible airbed or mattress I have, sleep for 6 to 7 hours and wake up in the morning before everyone else is back to work. So, from living viewpoint, the only thing they might notice is me sleeping there at night and nothing else.

About the homeless shelter, If I want use the address of a homeless shelter and give it to DMV for my driver's license, then, do I need to practically live in that homeless shelter everyday or I could just use the address without actually living there? If this is an option, then I guess I don't need a letterhead from my employer to state that I'm living in my workplace?

I just really don't understand why employer should have any problems with someone sleeping there at night for a few hours, they could interpret it as they just hired a hard-worker who wants to get up early in the morning and start the work rather than a homeless guy!"

Comment: Why would you want to be homeless?

Comment: Saving the rent.

Comment: If you live in your workplace then you are not homeless.

Comment: @NewbieWantsToMaster You know, if you are *truly* homeless and *truly* have no other choice then you have my sympathies. But honestly, the tone of your posts and you comments come off as if you are someone who has never worked but has never *truly* been homeless and see this as some kind of “game” to save money. Again, my apologies if that insulted you if you are *truly* homeless, but I don’t get the sense this is the case from your comments. If you want a real answer, you need to talk to a social worker in California. If yo are truly homeless you will need one—and a case worker—to help you.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere - I know man, I'm not sure how the situation is going to be interpreted by my employer, I have had the chance to live homeless in order to make it to somewhere better before, and I really think my new job in Calif is another opportunity for me to go homeless one more time and hopefully get to somewhere better one more time, but nothing is guaranteed. So I guess I should just see where the journey takes me...., I just want to keep things as legal as possible, that's why I asked the question here to get some insights about possible issues with being homeless in Calif....

Comment: I'm going to say I don't believe this question to be serious. Based on your other questions and answers you sound like you work in a IT field. I find it highly strange that someone of your field, who is capable of moving from cities, to have issues with homelessness.

Comment: No I don't work in IT, my field is actually Mechanical Eng, but I just can't resist to teach myself about entrepreneurship from coding to other sides of it. I have never had the chance to be surrounded with a lot of people who share an entrepreneurship spirit, I'm looking at moving to Calif as a chance to jump in the pool even though I don't know much swimming, in the hopes of coming to surface someday, and I'm ready to pay the price for that even though it's multiple years of homelessness, that's more like it....

Answer (score 9):

You will need the permission of your employer. They may decide that they don't want an employee to live on the premises. It may even be beyond their control. The local government could have zoning rules in place that don't allow somebody to live there.

The state DMV will require proof that the address you are giving is where you live. Here is the [list for California](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/brochures/fast_facts/ffdl5a) Residency documents marked with an asterisk (*) do not need to display the California address.:

- Rental/lease agreement with signatures of the owner/landlord and the
  tenant/resident.
- Deed title to residential real property.
- Mortgage bill
- Home utility bill (including cellular phones).
- School document.
- Medical document.
- Employment document.
- Faith-based document.
- Insurance document (example: vision, vehicle).
- Internal Revenue Service (IRS) or Franchise Tax Board (FTB) return.
- California DL/ID card.
- California vehicle/vessel Certificate of Title or registration.
- Change of address - confirmation from the U.S. Postal Service (Form CNL107).
- Documents issued by a government within the U.S. or the U.S. government.
- Property tax
- Financial institution record.
- Court documents indicating California residency.*
- Letter on letterhead from a homeless shelter, a shelter for abused women, nonprofit entity, employer, faith-based organization,
  or government within the U.S. attesting that the applicant is a
  resident of California.*
- A parent, legal guardian, or child may use a birth certificate and a spouse or domestic partner may use a marriage license or
  domestic partner registration certificate to trace his/her
  relationship to the individual to whom, one of the residency
  documents has been addressed.*

Comment: It may be very difficult to legitimately attain any of these if the employer does not endorse the plan of living in the workplace.

Comment: Wow, California must be lot more stick, in Kentucky I just used a copy of a TurboTax form, _that I filled out_.

Comment: By "live in workplace" I simply mean I'll work for 15 to 16 hours a day in my office (cubical) and when it's around 10-11pm I sleep there then wake up in the morning and start working again, so "live in workplace" only means sleeping there for 7 to 8 hours and nothing else. I'll be dressed professionally until right before sleep. And I'm not going to rent an apt somewhere else at all.

Comment: @NewbieWantsToMaster yes, that's what everyone thinks you mean, and is what their answers are about.

Answer (score 3):

The key issue to address is whether your employer is aware of and OK with the fact that you will live at the workplace.  While the idea of living at work may sound odd, there are circumstances where this is perfectly normal (e.g. Park and Forest Rangers, Caretakers).

If your employer is willing to let you live at your workplace, then they should have no problem giving you something on letterhead that you will reside at  to satisfy California DMV.

https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/brochures/fast_facts/ffdl5a

A cell phone bill is listed as one of the approved documents, and I've never had a cell phone company challenge me to provide them with proof of residency.  They simply accept whatever I give them.